# How to perform an union of two files containing keywords in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unions

I have 2 different text files.

File1.txt contains:

```
program
RAM
Python
parser
```

File2.txt contains:

```
file
1234
program
```

I want to perform an union of these both files such that i get an output file3.txt which contains:

```
program
RAM
Python
parser
file
1234
```

Is it possible to program this in python? I use python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("File1.txt") as fin1: lines = set(fin1.readlines())
with open("File2.txt") as fin2: lines.update(set(fin2.readlines()))
with open("file3.txt", 'w') as fout: fout.write('\n'.join(list(lines)))
```

Comment: It doesn't perform an union. It just combines the two files. I don't want the 'program' keyword to be repeated again.

Comment: Yes, I realized that and fixed it within a minute or so of posting. The current version uses a `set()` object.